# EF Many To Many Exisiting object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have the following database tables:

Document
Country (never added to)
DocumentLanguage

DocumentLanguage is a link table between Country and Document only containing the ID's. Entity designer (correctly) adds this a a navigation property.

My code is as follows:

```
 public void IdentifyLanguages(List<Country> languages)
    {
        foreach (Country c in languages)
        {
            foreach (var languageIdentifier in c.LanguageIdentifiers)
            {
                if (document.DocumentText.ToLower().Contains(languageIdentifier.LanguageIdentifier1.ToLower()))
                {                      
                   document.Countries.Add(c); 
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

and later save the object:

```
context.Document.AddObject(_document);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And i get the following error:

The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null.

There is probably a very obvious solutution, i have tried using attach, using stub objects, but there must be a simple solution as am sure i am not the first person who has had this requirment!

Answer (score 0):

When you save the object using AddObject, does your document already exist in your database?  AddObject is only for adding new objects, not updating existing ones

Comment: It is new when it is added, if i remove the call to IdentifyLanguages() it works, it is just adding the languages that is causing a problem.